# Curious for the Format of date

Tags: python

```
Date log

2007.793 2.765
2007.875 1.5
2007.96 12.5
2008.045 0.245
2008.127 0.545
2008.209 0.942
...
2008.962 6.54
```

Hi, I am curious what is the name of the format of Date.
The right part of the date is over 365, so I have no idea for that.
How can I make it as 'YYYY-mm-dd' format?

Comment: Where does this format comes from?

Comment: I have never seen that before, but if I had to guess it would be an ordinal date format using the percentage of year completed. I.e 2008.962 is the year 2008 and it is 96.2% completed.

Comment: _"The right part of the date is over 365, so I have no idea for that"_ - could be fractional years, i.e. `2008.962` would be 96% of the way through the year, ~17th December.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first token in each line represents a year and a fractional part of that year then you could do it like this...

```
from calendar import isleap
from time import strptime, strftime
from math import modf

dates = [
    "2007.793 2.765",
    "2007.875 1.5",
    "2007.96 12.5",
    "2008.045 0.245",
    "2008.127 0.545",
    "2008.209 0.942"
]


for line in dates:
    # isolate the year and its fractional part
    dp, year = modf(float(line.split()[0]))
    # calculate day in year
    diysf = round(dp * (366 if isleap(year) else 365))
    # format as YYYYDDD, parse, then reformat as DD-MM-YYYY
    print(strftime("%d-%m-%Y", strptime(f"{int(year):04d}{diysf:03d}", "%Y%j")))
```

**Output:**

```
16-10-2007
15-11-2007
16-12-2007
16-01-2008
15-02-2008
16-03-2008
```

Comment: I tried in python too with your code, and the values have differences 0 or 1 day each other. I am not sure which will provide the correct one and method to check it.

Comment: @Joe If you play around with the YEARFRAC function in Excel or Numbers you'll see that the results from my answer are very accurate

Comment: Wow thank you so much!!! I got helps from you a lot. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

It is called decimal year format.
The first part, before the decimal point (e.g., "2007"), represents the year.
The second part, after the decimal point (e.g., "0.793"), represents the fraction of the year that has passed.
So, for example, "2007.793" would correspond to a date approximately 79.3% of the way through the year 2007.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help. I could get the information of the format and got the solutions to solve it in excel. I wrote the solution and its reference link. Thank you!

=DATE(INT(A1), 1, 1)+MOD(A1,1)*(DATE(INT(A1)+1, 1, 1)-DATE(INT(A1), 1, 1))
(https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/decimal-year-to-date-conversion.920897/post-4426905)

Comment: @Joe Are you sure that Excel formula gives the correct results?